# Rewrite this line with the newer release of structuremap?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, structuremap

Hi I recently updated my version of structuremap to the latest release and i get prompted to change this line but I'm not really sure how, I tried tho but with no luck. This code works but I would like to user the new "way".

```
ForRequestedType<ISessionSourceConfiguration>().TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<MsSqlSessionSourceConfiguration>().WithCtorArg("connectionString").EqualTo(connectionString);
```

Same with this

```
For<INHibernateUnitOfWork>().CacheBy(InstanceScope.Hybrid).TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<NHibernateUnitOfWork>();
```

Thanks for tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
For<ISessionSourceConfiguration>().Use<MsSqlSessionSourceConfiguration>()
  .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(connectionString);
```

and

```
For<INHibernateUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
  .Use<NHibernateUnitOfWork>();
```